# Difference between ActionBarSherlock and ActionBar Compatibility

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

What is the difference between [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) and [Action Bar Compatibility](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ActionBarCompat/index.html)

Fews days ago Google just released the ActionBar Compatibility that make me so confused. Is that the Action Bar Compatibility works same as the ActionBarSherlock and is the coding same?

Example : Does [app icon to navigate "up"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled%28boolean%29) or ActionBar.Tab supported in Action Bar Compatibility ?

Comment: FYI I wrote a blog post about this for Square's eng blog: http://corner.squareup.com/2012/05/actionbarsherlock-as-a-base.html

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=Jl3-lzlzOJI#t=224

This is what Google thinks of ActionBarSherlock vs ActionBarCompact

Answer (score 60, accepted):

ActionBarSherlock gives your application an action bar regardless* of what version of the android API your app is being run on. Action Bar Compatibility gives you the action bar only if the device that you're running on is API level 3.0 or above.

*Note that if the device you're running on isn't 3.0 or above, ActionBarSherlock is going to use it's own custom implementation of the action bar, not a native one.

--EDIT--

It appears things have changed and there is actually no difference between ActionBarSherlock and the Action Bar Compatibility anymore. Please read the comments below for details.

--EDIT--

After having used both now, I can say that I actually prefer ActionBarSherlock to Action Bar Compatibility. ActionBarSherlock is really easy and nice to use.

--EDIT--
As LOG_TAG mentioned, there is now support for the action bar in the Android Support Library. I haven't had a chance to use it yet, but I would imagine that's the best one to use.

Comment: I just tested on 2.3.5 device , the Action Bar Compatibility also works on pre-API 11 devices. Does the Action Bar Compatibility just modify the activity title bar to make it have a actionbar design look ?

Comment: No, it's not modifiying the title bar. According to the website it "will automatically wrap a custom implementation around your layouts".

Comment: Ok, so the ActionBar.Tab , setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled , getActionBar() and others function that related to actionbar will not work on "Action Bar Compatibility" because it just wrap a custom implementation around the layouts ?

Comment: No, they'll work as long as the device it's being run on api 3 or up.

Comment: Ok, thanks I think I understand now. So if I want to use ActionBar.Tab and related function on pre-API 11 devices I have to use ActionBarSherlock right?

Comment: Action Bar Compatibility gives you the action bar only if the device that you're running on is API level 3.0 or above. = i guess this is wrong they can be used on pre-3.0.

Comment: @mikedroid I don't understand you're comment

Comment: I don't think this is actually the case.  According to http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ActionBarCompat/index.html, ActionBarCompatibility uses the built-in ActionBar on 3.0 and up, and a custom implementation pre-3.0, just like Sherlock does.  That page even has a screenshot of ActionBarCompatibility's custom implementation running on a Gingerbread device.


So then it seems both frameworks can provide a "faux action bar" on pre-3.0 devices, and the differences in fact lie elsewhere.

Comment: @Anidamo Thanks for the heads up. I might be going insane, but I could swear that at one point, the version in the android compatibility pack didn't give you one if your pre-3.0. I've modified my answer.

Comment: I reluctant to believe that there is no difference between both. What about ease of usage? What about tabs? What about landscape vs. portrait? Voting down.

Comment: Also, the answer is totally wrong - the purpose of the compatibility example is to support pre-3.0 devices.

Comment: So those with experience with this: Do you find the ActionBarCompatibility or ActionBarSherlock to be easier to implement? I was planning on using ABS and Jake's ViewPagerIndicator in order to give my apps that 4.0 look.

Comment: Edit is wrong there is a lot of difference between both of them

Comment: Google released a new backward-compatible Action Bar implementation called ActionBarCompat that's part of the Support Library r18. The ActionBarCompat APIs let you build the essential Action Bar design pattern into your app, with broad compatibility back to Android 2.1.

Comment: Following link tells you `why` and `how` to use the new ActionBarCompat API, http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/08/actionbarcompat-and-io-2013-app-source.html

Comment: ActionBar compatibility does not have support for adding ActionBar on a prefernceActivity, ActionBarSherlock does have this support. So they are not the same atleast as of now.

Comment: Just to add, for those who think they may want Chromecast integration in their app, I'd highly recommend using appcompat library.  The MediaRouter APIs necessary for Chromecast integration depends on appcompat; ActionBarSherlock cannot be used.

Comment: It might be a good idea to use ActionBarCompat since future development for ActionBarCompat has been stopped https://plus.google.com/+JakeWharton/posts/F3HkWY9J8fK

Answer (score 113):

**ActionBarSherlock vs ActionBarCompat:**

I Just want to put few code difference between ActionBarSherlock vs ActionBarCompat Lib

[image: ActionBarSherlock vs ActionBarCompat **strong text**]

**We can migrate some apps from ActionBarSherlock to ActionBarCompat:**

steps:

1. Import *AppCompat* project.
2. Replace *`SherlockFragmentActivity`* with *`ActionBarActivity`*.
3. Replace *`SherlockFragment`* with *`Fragment`*.
4. Change `Menu`, *`MenuItem`* and *`getSupportMenuInflater()`* references.
   Modify the way you get Action Views.

   *`mSearchView = (SearchView)MenuItemCompat.getActionView(mSearchItem)`*
5. Modify your *Themes* and *Styles*.

For more info, please refer this slides by [+NickButcher](https://plus.google.com/+NickButcher/posts/bGWotMzC985) (Google)

> [image]

Thanks to Sources: 
http://gmariotti.blogspot.in/2013/07/actionbarsherlock-vs-actionbarcompat.html
http://antonioleiva.com/actionbarcompat-migrating-actionbarsherlock/

Don't forget to read this [developer.android](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/index.html) for more about ABC!

Note: Setting it up for unit tests the same way as ABS is unfortunately not possible with the support library.

Output:

> [image]

Credits: Gabriele Mariotti

Comment: Just an update that ABS can now also be added to Gradle projects via `compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'` and doesn't have to be a library project.

Comment: Thanks for the detail explanation

Answer (score 41):

Just completing what @Kurtis Nusbaum with a pratical example.

UPDATE: as @rudy-s said, with newest android support library (api 18), I saw they already have built-in support for actionbar (called ActionBarCompat class).

I built two simple applications to show the visual difference between ActionBarSherlock and ActionBar Compatibility. See the comparatives images:

### [image: App using compatibility library]

### [image: App using sherlock library]

Now the appearance when the menu button is pressed:

### [image: App using compatibility on menu pressed]

[image: App using sherlock on menu pressed]

---

As you can see, the images just enforce what was said. **Action Bar Compatibility gives you the action bar only if the device that you're running on is API level 3.0 or above. While Sherlock is more general.**

Below you can see the application source.

The menu xml file is the same:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_1"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/action1"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_2"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/action2"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_3"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/action3"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

</menu>
```

Compatibility's activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
     }
}
```

Sherlock's activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu) {
        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

}
```

An additional config was necessary on sherlock app:

`<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">`

UPDATE:
as @rudy-s said, with newest android support library (api 18), I saw they already have built-in support for actionbar (called ActionBarCompat class).

Comment: Actually, this is not entirely correct. The Compat library can, and does give you an ActionBar implementation on Gingerbread. This app for example gives you an AB on GB and does not use Sherlock but Compat. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.mxdata.rootle

Comment: There is no need, if you pull that actionbarcompat sample out (for example out of the android-17 sdk) and build it in ADT, it will run on a GB device with an ActionBar. I just tested it myself to confirm on a Desire HD with 2.3.5.

Comment: Ok, I got it. However, ActionBarSherlock provides more features, isn't it?

Comment: With newest android support library (api 18), I saw they already have built-in support for actionbar (called ActionBarCompat class).

Comment: GingerBEARD?  Love it.

Answer (score 39):

Actionbar Sherlock is far more advanced and far more ambitious than the simple Actionbar compatibility project.

The Action bar compatibility can be considered a "sample" or a good starting point if you only want to smack an Action Bar on top of your app.

ActionBarSherlock builds on the compatibility library, and gives you (like the action bar compatibility sample) an Action Bar on pre-3.0 devices. In addition it has extra features not present in the ActionBar Compat code. This includes features like, but not limited to

- setNavigationMode (for Tabs and spinners in the action bar)
- Dialog Fragments
- Contextual Action Bar (CAB) a menu that takes over the action bar, used for example for multi select (http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/new-4-0.html) This is a ICS feature (!) For this, an implementation of the ActionMode class (introduced in API level 11) had to be introduced into the ActionbarSherlock library
- Fragment and FragmentActivity implementations - because fragments can implement the onCreateOptions menu, we need to make sure that the SupportMenuInflater is used.
- Two themes not very unlike Holo.Dark and Holo.Light (Theme.Sherlock, Theme.Sherlock.Light)
- The ICS feature "split action bar"

The only downside I see in using ActionbarSherlock is that you lock yourself in to that library. If for some reason it will die out in the near future, you'll have to maintain it youself (for example if no Jellybean implementation comes along). This is a hassle (not a huge problem) since all your fragments extends SherlockFragemnt and all your Activities.
 SherlockActivity.

Comment: Am I missing something? It seems that multi select is NOT support in ABS

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Multi select is not by itself supported by ABS. But, you can implement Multiselect by using the ABS "ActionMode", as ABS has its own implementations of the ActionMode classes. When going into "multi select mode", You would set the ListView's  choice mode to CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE, and invoke ActionMode by calling   getSherlockActivity().startActionMode(callback)

Answer (score 26):

Well @Jake implementation goes way further than what the Actionbar compat, to be more precise Actionbar Compat is just a basic example on how can you support all aplication with a pseudo-actionbar for releases prior from Honeycomb (API 13). Although their target is the same cross compatible actionbar, they have diferent approach.

**ActionbarCompat Aproach**

This implementation make no use of the Compatibility Android support library instead it create a base class called [ActionBarActivity](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ActionBarCompat/src/com/example/android/actionbarcompat/ActionBarActivity.html) create a single instance of a [Helper](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ActionBarCompat/src/com/example/android/actionbarcompat/ActionBarHelper.html) this helper act as factory itself that returns diferent implementation for the three segment of APIS, it returns

- [ActionbarBaseHelper](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ActionBarCompat/src/com/example/android/actionbarcompat/ActionBarHelperBase.html): for prior to HoneyComb.
- [ActionBarHoneyComb](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ActionBarCompat/src/com/example/android/actionbarcompat/ActionBarHelperHoneycomb.html): for HoneyComb
- [ActionBarHelperICS](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ActionBarCompat/src/com/example/android/actionbarcompat/ActionBarHelperICS.html): for ICS base devices.

The most interesting part is in the [ActionbarBaseHelper](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ActionBarCompat/src/com/example/android/actionbarcompat/ActionBarHelperBase.html), because it has the most important code, I suggest you understand this class and you will get the whole example.

**Action Bar Sherlock**

Well this is tricky firstable because, I'm not the author maybe Jake can explained further this, but I'll give it a try.

Just as the compat Sherlock make diferent implementation but one is for "Compat" and the other is Native. It force you to extends either from SherlockActivity or from SherlockFragmentActivity, because this two base classes have the method for dispatching the ActionBar.

This is a large and complex project, that cannot be explained in a single post. Suggest you dig around [Sherlock Github repo](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock) grab a look and as [Jeff Atwood](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/04/learn-to-read-the-source-luke.html) says

[image]

Answer (score 10):

- I strongly believe that you should use `ActionBarCompat` for all new
  projects that want to support older devices.
- It also might make sense to migrate existing projects. So read on to
  learn why you should migrate or use ActionBarCompat right away and
  how to migrate existing projects.

**Why you should prefer ActionBarCompat over ActionBarSherlock?**

There are many reasons why you should prefer ActionbarCompat over ActionbarSherlock.

1. First of all this project is by Google, is part of the Support
   Library and thus likely will support new Action Bar related stuff at
   the same time Google releases them with stock Android.
2. Another good reason is that it supports the `Navigation Drawer
   pattern` right out of the box, while ActionBarSherlock does not. Thus
   if you want to add this drawer to an existing project/app you should
   migrate.
3. The last and Important  is, that the creator of ActionBarSherlock,
   Jake Wharton, announced on Google+ that further development of
   ActionBarSherlock has been stopped. ActionBarSherlock 4.4 is the
   last release and might get bug fixes – but there won’t be any new
   features:  So if new functionality is included in actionbar you may
   not keep up to it  with actionbarsherlock.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe we should update the answer because google published offical Actionbar support since [API18](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html#revisions)?

block below is from [offical blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/08/actionbarcompat-and-io-2013-app-source.html) about these two libraries:

> If you’re using a third-party solution (such as ActionBarSherlock), there are a few reasons to consider upgrading:
>
> - Can be kept updated as the Action Bar API evolves.
> - Integrated Ancestral Navigation support.
> - Use of framework Menu and MenuItem classes.
> - Continue to use the Support Library's Fragment class.
> - Integrated support for ActionBarDrawerToggle for use with DrawerLayout.
> - Backport of PopupMenu.
>
> ActionBarSherlock is a solid and well-tested library which has served developers very well for a long time. If you are already using it and do not currently require any of the above then there is no need to migrate.