# What are these controls that I can use in my android-app?

Tags: android, tabs, fragment

I have seen a great user control component in an Android app. I do not know what is it.
Here is a screenshot of this app:

[image]

I am interested in the user control components under the "thumb" label. What is it? I have googled already but found only the `TabActivity` which is already a deprecated feature.

What do I have to use instead to make it look like the above screen-shot?

I found this blog [entry](http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/04/android-tabs-the-fragment-way/) about tab-controls; is this the right way for making that tab-control?

I wanna use it under Android 2.2+.

Comment: looks ok, there is also a similar official example for tabs with fragments [FragmentTabs](https://github.com/android/platform_development/blob/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/FragmentTabs.java). Those tabs can be [customized](http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=136)

Comment: Good example but so much useless source code. I don't understand, why Google community can't write simple example of using Tabs. The FragmentTabs.java includes ["LoaderThrottle.ThrottledLoaderListFragment.class"](https://github.com/android/platform_development/blob/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/LoaderThrottle.java) which contains 512 lines. For what?? Simple tab android app needs to write 512 lines to start work with tabs??

Comment: By the way, the FragmenTabs example is based on ActionBar which comes in Android 3.0. But I need tabs in android 2.2 :(

Comment: the `ThrottledLoaderListFragment` is just a sample fragment to have something to show inside the tabs. You can safely ignore the content. [This FragmentTabs](https://github.com/android/platform_development/blob/master/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentTabs.java) example uses fragments through the compatibility library (API level 4+) with tabs, no action bar & not deprecated

Comment: When I to to execute: "ActionBar bar = getActionBar();" in Android 2.2 project, I get an error: "ActionBar cannot be resolved to a type". When I try to execute that in Android 3.2 - it works fine... Do you happen to know why it works like this?

Comment: Android 2.2 has no ActionBar, see http://developer.android.com/training/backward-compatible-ui/abstracting.html or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844517/different-between-actionbarsherlock-and-action-bar-compatibility

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you looking for an iPhone like tab bar ? here are few examples on Android tab bar and few others
Check if it helps you.. [Iphone Like Tab bar in Android](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-iphone-like-tab-bar-in-android/)

Cheers