# Is actionbarsherlock needed anymore?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-support-library

Since you can use ActionBar from the v7 appcompat library in the support library, is there any reason to use actionbarsherlock anymore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer This question to wheter you want to use actionsharlock or not:
Also it have a detail compare in screen between two:

[Difference between ActionBarSherlock and ActionBar Compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844517/difference-between-)
actionbarsherlock-and-actionbar-compatibility

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but they are talking about a different stuff (since the Actionbar is only part of the support lib since 2013 july-or-so, and the question there was asked in 2011). They only mention the new stuff, but I didin't see an exact answer. Anyway, as far as I know there is not much difference.

Answer (score 5):

If you develop a new app, you should consider ActionBarCompat as your first choice.
Google put more devs to support that lib in the future.

If your app is using ActionBarSherlock, keep using it, or migrate to ActionBarCompat to get some other functionalities and supporting from GG Android team.

Answer (score 2):

Actionbar sherlock will not upgrade anymore so consider using appcompat