# Navigation Drawer ListView selection problems on android 2.3

Tags: android, listviewitem, android-2.3-gingerbread, navigation-drawer

I try to customize navigation drawer menu for old-good android 2.3
For this I use official **SampleNavigationDrawer** by developer.android.com
and [this tutorial for implements **ActionBarCompat**](http://gmariotti.blogspot.it/2013/07/actionbarcompat-and-navigationdrawer.html).

In **android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout** use next ListView:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#111"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    android:fadingEdge="none"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:saveEnabled="true" />
```

with drawer_list_item.xml:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_selector"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/selector"
    android:drawablePadding="16dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="48dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:textColor="@drawable/text_color_selector" />
```

bg_selector.xml :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/yellow" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/red" />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@color/lemon" />
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@color/orange" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/green_pastel" />
    <item android:state_active="true" android:drawable="@color/gold" />
    <item android:state_accelerated="true" android:drawable="@color/blue" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@color/pink_dark" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/black" />
</selector>
```

selector.xml :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/action_search" />
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_drawer" />
</selector>
```

text_color_selector.xml :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/blue" />
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:color="@color/green_pastel_dark" />
    <item android:color="@color/white" />
</selector>
```

### **Problem :**

[For API14+ it looks awesome but on android 2.3.6 selector isn't shown. (**see this screenshots**)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gn7C7.jpg)

**P.S.** 
state_activated parameter was not introduced until API level 11

Comment: What exactly is your problem regarding the selection of items in your navigation drawer?

Comment: @jeraldov the onClick behavior is the same and work good. But i want   UI look the same on API8 and API14+

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14261981/334270

Answer (score 1):

Try using ActionBar Sherlock instead. Here are some good tutorials for it:
http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/implementing-actionbarsherlock-side-menu-navigation-with-fragment-tabs-tutorial/

http://techbandhu.wordpress.com/2013/05/25/navigation-drawer-android/

Comment: ActionBarCompat is official implementation of ActionBar for compatibility with Android 2.1 (API level 7) and above. and I hope it is allow do the same (like ABS).
But now i do not know how..

Comment: This should help you see the difference between ActionBarCompat and ActionBarSherlock.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844517/difference-between-actionbarsherlock-and-actionbar-compatibility