# Navigation Drawer is not working in android 2.3

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-2.3-gingerbread

I tried navigation drawer  it worked fine  in android 4.1 Then I tried in gingerbread,I added supported library appcompat  still also I am getting error please help me

```
01-02 16:48:04.765: E/AndroidRuntime(4688): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-02 16:48:04.765: E/AndroidRuntime(4688): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.javatechig.drawer.MainActivity.getActionBar
01-02 16:48:04.765: E/AndroidRuntime(4688):     at com.javatechig.drawer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
01-02 16:48:04.765: E/AndroidRuntime(4688):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-02 16:48:04.765: E/AndroidRuntime(4688):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
01-02 16:48:04.765: E/AndroidRuntime(4688):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
01-02 16:48:04.765: E/AndroidRuntime(4688):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-02 16:48:04.765: E/AndroidRuntime(4688):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
01-02 16:48:04.765: E/AndroidRuntime(4688):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-02 16:48:04.765: E/AndroidRuntime(4688):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-02 16:48:04.765: E/AndroidRuntime(4688):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
01-02 16:48:04.765: E/AndroidRuntime(4688):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-02 16:48:04.765: E/AndroidRuntime(4688):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-02 16:48:04.765: E/AndroidRuntime(4688):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
01-02 16:48:04.765: E/AndroidRuntime(4688):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
01-02 16:48:04.765: E/AndroidRuntime(4688):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`getSupportActionBar()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html#getSupportActionBar%28%29), which is a support library version of getActionBar().

To use all the support methods, you need to extend [**ActionBarActivity**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html) class instead of `Activity` class.

Comment: I used library also but i am not getting getsupportactionbar()

Comment: @peter what is the version of support library which you are using?

Comment: android-support-v7-appcompat

Comment: I am getting another exception   Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x10102fd a=-1}

Comment: @peter so that's why you are playing with accepting/not accepting answer? I don't know where have you referenced/used any resources in your code. Can't suggest!

Comment: i extended actionbaractivity and added theme.appcompat after that i got this error

Answer (score 0):

This is because they are using Actionbar, action bar supports from 3.0 onwards. In order to support for 2.3 they need to use sherlock action bar. See this:
http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Comment: He has already mentioned *I added supported library appcompat*, did you read that?

Answer (score 0):

Try using ActionBar Sherlock instead. Here are some good tutorials for it:http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/implementing-actionbarsherlock-side-menu-navigation-with-fragment-tabs-tutorial/

This should help you see the difference between ActionBarCompat and ActionBarSherlock.[Difference between ActionBarSherlock and ActionBar Compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844517/difference-between-actionbarsherlock-and-actionbar-compatibility)

Answer (score -1):

The Actionbar is added in android 3.0 so it is not supported in android 2.3 So Use the [Go to The Link](http://actionbarsherlock.com/%E2%80%8E) and download the library and add it to your project.

Comment: He has already mentioned *I added supported library appcompat*, did you read that?

Comment: I was simultaneously composing the answer when you were. So, I don't know that you posted

Comment: this was just coincidence.