# Android: SlidingMenu vs DrawerLayout

Tags: android, navigation

What to use in 2015: [SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) or [`android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout`](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)?

SlidingMenu seems to be popular but it is not updated since 10 Mar 2014

It seems like other example of Android standard thing superpassing some third parties libs, like [ActionBarSherlock vs ActionBar Compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844517/difference-between-actionbarsherlock-and-actionbar-compatibility).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most people gave up trying to implement their own menu implementations once Google released the support version (ABS is another example of this). Like you said, the library you mentioned has not been updated in almost a year, and it has 218 open issues.

I would suggest using the DrawerLayout, since it seamlessly integrates with AppCompat Material Design theme. It should also be easier to update and maintain in the future.

The other nice thing about DrawerLayout is that there are a ton of how-tos on the internet, answering just about any question you could have.