# How to import Action Bar Sherlock? android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, actionbarsherlock, android-appcompat

I want to export and import a gradle project which I used in Android with Eclipse.

Problems importing project into Android Studio regarding ActionBarSherlock

```
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:17'
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.matetek.Hello"
        minSdkVersion 14
        android:targetSdkVersion="23"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
    dependencies {
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
}
```

cannot use

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity

also

```
Error:(10, 0) Cause: startup failed:
build file 'C:\Work\Hello\build.gradle': 10: Statement labels may not be used in build scripts.
In case you tried to configure a property named 'android', replace ':' with '=' or ' ', otherwise it will not have the desired effect.
 @ line 10, column 17.
           android:targetSdkVersion="23"
```

Help me

I'm sorry I`m not good at English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the  `android:targetSdkVersion="23"` to `targetSdkVersion 23` It will work.

For more info go through developer site : [Android Build Configuring](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html)

Also use the latest support library

```
compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
```

Comment: As said by Gabriele Mariotti  It's better to use **AppCompat** Lib http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844517/difference-between-actionbarsherlock-and-actionbar-compatibility

Answer (score 4):

First of all, the [Actionbarsherlock library](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock) **was deprecated** by the author 2 years ago.
There is no need to use this library today.
Use the the **AppCompat library**, in this way you will able to use all the new features and the new support libraries (as the design support library).

Your issue is here.

```
defaultConfig {
        android:targetSdkVersion="23"
    }
```

Change this line in

```
defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }
```

Pay attention.
**You can't use together ActionbarSherlock and Appcompat library.**

They use the same attributes.

Comment: I just copied project  into studio , This project use action .so If I change action into app , this project will work without errors?

Comment: what do you mean with "this project use action"?

Comment: ActionbarSherlock ... sorry

Comment: You have to change something in your code of course.